# to finish reverting please merge and commit the change

Tags: git, github

I got this weird as cow behavior from the git app. I basically want to revert to one of the past commit. The app keeps telling me to merge and commit changes. While there nothing to commit. All the new code were committed already.

How can I fix this thing?

And screenshot[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update2: I tried to revert with command line and got this message

```
MacBook:trutit vanvan$ git revert 69638b3
error: could not revert 69638b3... Revert "add grid system"
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve **exactly** ? (`revert to one of the past commit` seems unclear to me) What's the expected result ? What commands did you run ? What's the actual result ? What's the exact message do you get ? Maybe you can add a screenshot of your `gitk` screen ;)

Comment: @pomeh updated question

Comment: Cool, but better if you include details in your initial message: *1)* this enable text search, *2)* all required content is in one place, better for helping you, *3)* link may be down/removed in the future, *4)* people may not have access to the link content (dropbox.com is blocked by my current corporate proxy)

Comment: What you are doing on those screenshots/video is reverting _a_ commit, i.e. applying a reversed diff of that commit on top of the current branch (that's what `git revert` does). But I think what you actually want is to reset the current branch to that commit, making that commit the new top of the branch.

Comment: thanks for distinguishing that. I had no idea they are different. You think right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `git reset`:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

I don't know, whether there is an option in that GUI, but in the console it will be

```
git reset --hard commit_identifier
```

**Warning:** it will erase all unsaved changes and all commits made after `commit_identifier`.

Comment: would git reset remove all commit history hence no more trace back?

Comment: It will make all commits after `commit_identifier` disappear from the current branch (as if they were never there). And if you change your mind, you can [recover](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery) those commits from the reflog. But if you already pushed those commits to a remote repository, they will stay there, and there isn't much you can do about it. Or what exactly did you mean by "no more trace back"?

Comment: never mind 'the no more trace back'. I just know the correct term. but its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to attempt to fix this, look at the **Fixing** section. Otherwise, skip ahead to the **Backing out** section.

## Fixing

**Step 1: Fix conflicts (manually or by using `git checkout`)**

Looks like there was a merge conflict when git attempted to revert to the older commit. Look for merge conflict markers in your files (`<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` arrows) and fix them to the version you prefer.

You can either edit the files manually, or if you're sure that you want to keep old commit's version of a file, you can do:

```
git checkout --theirs <filenames>
```

Alternatively to keep `HEAD`'s version of the file:

```
git checkout --ours <filenames>
```

This will save you the pain of manually editing the files.

**Step 2: Seal the deal**

When you have finished resolving merge conflicts, run these commands from the command line (or their equivalent in the Github app):

```
git commit -am "Resolve merge conflicts during revert"
git revert --continue
```

This should ideally leave your repo in the desired state.

## Backing out

In case you just want to get out of this mess and start over, run:

```
git revert --abort
```

This will put you back in the original state before you initially attempted `git revert`.

Comment: Glad you asked. 

You can run `git checkout --theirs filename.txt` to keep the old commit's version, or `git checkout --ours filename.txt` to keep `HEAD`'s version. Repeat this for each of the files or simply use the `*` operator to apply this to all files.